# Correct way to store passwords in protractor config file

Tags: angular

I am writing some e2e tests for my Angular 2 application with Protractor. At the moment, I login with facebook with an onprepare function in my protractor configuration.

Currently I have my facebook login and password hardcoded in my config file, I was wondering what would be the best way to store sensitive data like this? Enviroment variables?